# URL Readable by urllib in Python 2 but not in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I can read a specific web page in Python2 quite easily:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlopen("http://www.pluralsight.com/authors")
<addinfourl at 4566566312 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x10fd18a50>>
```

When I try to read the same URL using Python3, however, I get an exception:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> urlopen("http://www.pluralsight.com/authors")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 461, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 571, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 499, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 579, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `urllib.request.urlopen` is equivalent to Python2's `urllib2.urlopen`, and `urllib.urlopen` has been removed.

You can see the differences and why you're getting an error in Python 3 in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947133/urllib2-urlopen-vs-urllib-urlopen-urllib2-throws-404-while-urllib-works-w). Basically, `urllib2.urlopen` (`urllib.request.urlopen` in Python 3) handles the error for you, raising an exception, while `urllib.urlopen` just gives you the error as plain HTML.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Python 3 code I published uses urllib.request.urlopen.

Comment: @holdenweb Yes, and in your Python 2 code you're using `urllib` instead of `urllib2`. The functions are not equivalent.

Comment: I don't use urllib2 anywhere, so I don't understand your comments.

Comment: @holdenweb You're getting different results because you're using different functions. `urllib.request.urlopen` is not the same function as `urllib.urlopen` (in Python 2), but `urllib2.urlopen`. Did you see the difference?

Comment: @holdenweb Because `urllib.request.urlopen` is equivalent to Python2's `urllib2.urlopen`.

Comment: @holdenweb Can you see the differences between the `urllib` and `urllib2` modules?

Comment: Now I see - when I read your answer I didn't see the "2". I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it wasn't working in Python2 either:

```
u = urllib.urlopen("http://www.pluralsight.com/authors")
u.read()
#'<html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>\nRequest 
#forbidden by administrative rules.\n</body></html>\n\n'
```

Comment: Thanks. Guess they don't want this page scraped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a user-agent:

```
import urllib
req = urllib.request.Request(
    "http://www.pluralsight.com/authors",
     headers={
         'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
    }
)


print(urllib.request.urlopen(req).read())
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<!--[if IE 8]>\r\n    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en" ng-app="pluralsightModule">\r\n<![endif]-->\r\n<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->\r\n<html class="no-js" lang="en" ng-app="pluralsightModule" id="ng-app">\r\n<!--<![endif]-->\r\n<head>\r\n    <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;" /><script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info = {"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"2700af8a3c","applicationID":"3058581","transactionName":"Z1ZRN0EDCEMDABVYWl4cdwxHLANEIQwPRUdfX18GQU0nRRYLDkNGH3pdB1Ya","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":3,"ttGuid":"88B4BF5354B4582F","agent":"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-593.min.js"}</script><script type="text/javascript">(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={xpid:"VwUGVl5VGwAAUVlXDwA="};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,e,n){function r(n){if(!e[n]){var o=e[n]={exports:{}};t[n][0].call(o.exports,function(e){var o=t[n][1][e];return r(o?o:e)},o,o.exports)}return e[n].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o<n.length;o++)r(n[o]);return r}({QJf3ax:[function(t,e){function n(t){function e(e,n,a){t&&t(e,n,a),a||(a={});for(var c=s(e),f=c.length,u=i(a,o,r),d=0;f>d;d++)c[d].apply(u,n);return u}function a(t,e){f[t]=s(t).concat(e)}function s(t){return f[t]||[]}function c(){return n(e)}var f={};return{on:a,emit:e,create:c,listeners:s,_events:f}}function r(){return{}}var o="nr@context",i=t("gos");e.exports=n()},{gos:"7eSDFh"}],ee:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("QJf3ax")},{}],3:[function(t){function e(t){try{i.console&&console.log(t)}catch(e){}}var n,r=t("ee"),o=t(1),i={};try{n=localStorage.getItem("__nr_flags").split(","),console&&"function"==typeof console.log&&(i.console=!0,-1!==n.indexOf("dev")&&(i.dev=!0),-1!==n.indexOf("nr_dev")&&(i.nrDev=!0))}catch(a){}i.nrDev&&r.on("internal-error",function(t){e(t.stack)}),i.dev&&r.on("fn-err",function(t,n,r){e(r.stack)}),i.dev&&(e("NR AGENT IN DEVELOPMENT MODE"),e("flags: "+o(i,function(t){return t}).join(", ")))},{1:23,ee:"QJf3ax"}],4:[function(t){function e(t,e,n,i,s){try{c?c-=1:r("err",[s||new UncaughtException(t,e,n)])}catch(f){try{r("ierr",[f,(new Date).getTime(),!0])}catch(u){}}return"function"==typeof a?a.apply(this,o(arguments)):!1}function UncaughtException(t,e,n){this.message=t||"Uncaught error with no additional information",this.sourceURL=e,this.line=n}function n(t){r("err",[t,(new Date).getTime()])}var r=t("handle"),o=t(6),i=t("ee"),a=window.onerror,s=!1,c=0;t("loader").features.err=!0,t(4),window.onerror=e;try{throw new Error}catch(f){"stack"in f&&(t(1),t(5),"addEventListener"in window&&t(2),window.XMLHttpRequest&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener&&t(3),s=!0)}i.on("fn-start",function(){s&&(c+=1)}),i.on("fn-err",function(t,e,r){s&&(this.thrown=!0,n(r))}),i.on("fn-end",function(){s&&!this.thrown&&c>0&&(c-=1)}),i.on("internal-error",function(t){r("ierr",[t,(new Date).getTime(),!0])})},{1:10,2:7,3:11,4:3,5:9,6:24,ee:"QJf3ax",handle:"D5DuLP",loader:"G9z0Bl"}],5:[function(t){t("loader").features.ins=!0},{loader:"G9z0Bl"}],6:[function(t){function e(){}if(window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&window.performance.getEntriesByType){var n=t("ee"),r=t("handle"),o=t(1);t("loader").features.stn=!0,t(2),n.on("fn-start",function(t){var e=t[0];e instanceof Event&&(this.bstStart=Date.now())}),n.on("fn-end",function(t,e){var n=t[0];n instanceof Event&&r("bst",[n,e,this.bstStart,Date.now()])}),o.on("fn-start",function(t,e,n){this.bstStart=Date.now(),this.bstType=n}),o.on("fn-end",function(t,e){r("bstTimer",[e,this.bstStart,Date.now(),this.bstType])}),n.on("pushState-start",function(){this.time=Date.now(),this.startPath=location.pathname+location.hash}),n.on("pushState-end",function(){r("bstHist",[location.pathname+location.hash,this.startPath,this.time])}),"addEventListener"in window.performance&&(window.performance.addEventListener("webkitresourcetimingbufferfull",function(){r("bstResource",[window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource")]),window.performance.webkitClearResourceTimings()},!1),window.performance.addEventListener("resourcetimingbufferfull",function(){r("bstResource",[window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource")]),window.performance.clearResourceTimings()},!1)),document.addEventListener("scroll",e,!1),document.addEventListener("keypress",e,!1),document.addEventListener("click",e,!1)}},{1:10,2:8,ee:"QJf3ax",handle:"D5DuLP",loader:"G9z0Bl"}],7:[function(t,e){function n(t){i.inPlace(t,["addEventListener","removeEventListener"],"-",r)}function r(t){return t[1]}var o=(t(1),t("ee").create()),i=t(2)(o),a=t("gos");if(e.exports=o,n(window),"getPrototypeOf"in Object){for(var s=document;s&&!s.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener");)s=Object.getPrototypeOf(s);s&&n(s);for(var c=XMLHttpRequest.prototype;c&&!c.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener");)c=Object.getPrototypeOf(c);c&&n(c)}else XMLHttpRequest.prototype.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener")&&n(XMLHttpRequest.prototype);o.on("addEventListener-start",function(t){if(t[1]){var e=t[1];"function"==typeof e?this.wrapped=t[1]=a(e,"nr@wrapped",function(){return i(e,"fn-",null,e.name||"anonymous")}):"function"==typeof e.handleEvent&&i.inPlace(e,["handleEvent"],"fn-")}}),o.on("removeEventListener-start",function(t){var e=this.wrapped;e&&(t[1]=e)})},{1:24,2:25,ee:"QJf3ax",gos:"7eSDFh"}],8:[function(t,e){var n=(t(2),t("ee").create()),r=t(1)(n);e.exports=n,r.inPlace(window.history,["pushState"],"-")},{1:25,2:24,ee:"QJf3ax"}],9:[function(t,e){var n=(t(2),t("ee").create()),r=t(1)(n);e.exports=n,r.inPlace(window,["requestAnimationFrame","mozRequestAnimationFrame","webkitRequestAnimationFrame","msRequestAnimationFrame"],"raf-"),n.on("raf-start",function(t){t[0]=r(t[0],"fn-")})},{1:25,2:24,ee:"QJf3ax"}],10:[function(t,e){function n(t,e,n){var r=t[0];"string"==typeof r&&(r=new Function(r)),t[0]=o(r,"fn-",null,n)}var r=(t(2),t("ee").create()),o=t(1)(r);e.exports=r,o.inPlace(window,["setTimeout","setInterval","setImmediate"],"setTimer-"),r.on("setTimer-start",n)},{1:25,2:24,ee:"QJf3ax"}],11:[function(t,e){function n(){f.inPlace(this,p,"fn-")}function r(t,e){f.inPlace(e,["onreadystatechange"],"fn-")}function o(t,e){return e}function i(t,e){for(var n in t)e[n]=t[n];return e}var a=t("ee").create(),s=t(1),c=t(2),f=c(a),u=c(s),d=window.XMLHttpRequest,p=["onload","onerror","onabort","onloadstart","onloadend","onprogress","ontimeout"];e.exports=a,window.XMLHttpRequest=function(t){var e=new d(t);try{a.emit("new-xhr",[],e),u.inPlace(e,["addEventListener","removeEventListener"],"-",function(t,e){return e}),e.addEventListener("readystatechange",n,!1)}catch(r){try{a.emit("internal-error",[r])}catch(o){}}return e},i(d,XMLHttpRequest),XMLHttpRequest.prototype=d.prototype,f.inPlace(XMLHttpRequest.prototype,["open","send"],"-xhr-",o),a.on("send-xhr-start",r),a.on("open-xhr-start",r)},{1:7,2:25,ee:"QJf3ax"}],12:[function(t){function e(t){if("string"==typeof t&&t.length)return t.length;if("object"!=typeof t)return void 0;if("undefined"!=typeof ArrayBuffer&&t instanceof ArrayBuffer&&t.byteLength)return t.byteLength;if("undefined"!=typeof Blob&&t instanceof Blob&&t.size)return t.size;if("undefined"!=typeof FormData&&t instanceof FormData)return void 0;try{return JSON.stringify(t).length}catch(e){return void 0}}function n(t){var n=this.params,r=this.metrics;if(!this.ended){this.ended=!0;for(var i=0;c>i;i++)t.removeEventListener(s[i],this.listener,!1);if(!n.aborted){if(r.duration=(new Date).getTime()-this.startTime,4===t.readyState){n.status=t.status;var a=t.responseType,f="arraybuffer"===a||"blob"===a||"json"===a?t.response:t.responseText,u=e(f);if(u&&(r.rxSize=u),this.sameOrigin){var d=t.getResponseHeader("X-NewRelic-App-Data");d&&(n.cat=d.split(", ").pop())}}else n.status=0;r.cbTime=this.cbTime,o("xhr",[n,r,this.startTime])}}}function r(t,e){var n=i(e),r=t.params;r.host=n.hostname+":"+n.port,r.pathname=n.pathname,t.sameOrigin=n.sameOrigin}if(window.XMLHttpRequest&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent)){t("loader").features.xhr=!0;var o=t("handle"),i=t(2),a=t("ee"),s=["load","error","abort","timeout"],c=s.length,f=t(1);t(4),t(3),a.on("new-xhr",function(){this.totalCbs=0,this.called=0,this.cbTime=0,this.end=n,this.ended=!1,this.xhrGuids={}}),a.on("open-xhr-start",function(t){this.params={method:t[0]},r(this,t[1]),this.metrics={}}),a.on("open-xhr-end",function(t,e){"loader_config"in NREUM&&"xpid"in NREUM.loader_config&&this.sameOrigin&&e.setRequestHeader("X-NewRelic-ID",NREUM.loader_config.xpid)}),a.on("send-xhr-start",function(t,n){var r=this.metrics,o=t[0],i=this;if(r&&o){var f=e(o);f&&(r.txSize=f)}this.startTime=(new Date).getTime(),this.listener=function(t){try{"abort"===t.type&&(i.params.aborted=!0),("load"!==t.type||i.called===i.totalCbs&&(i.onloadCalled||"function"!=typeof n.onload))&&i.end(n)}catch(e){try{a.emit("internal-error",[e])}catch(r){}}};for(var u=0;c>u;u++)n.addEventListener(s[u],this.listener,!1)}),a.on("xhr-cb-time",function(t,e,n){this.cbTime+=t,e?this.onloadCalled=!0:this.called+=1,this.called!==this.totalCbs||!this.onloadCalled&&"function"==typeof n.onload||this.end(n)}),a.on("xhr-load-added",function(t,e){var n=""+f(t)+!!e;this.xhrGuids&&!this.xhrGuids[n]&&(this.xhrGuids[n]=!0,this.totalCbs+=1)}),a.on("xhr-load-removed",function(t,e){var n=""+f(t)+!!e;this.xhrGuids&&this.xhrGuids[n]&&(delete this.xhrGuids[n],this.totalCbs-=1)}),a.on("addEventListener-end",function(t,e){e instanceof XMLHttpRequest&&"load"===t[0]&&a.emit("xhr-load-added",[t[1],t[2]],e)}),a.on("removeEventListener-end",function(t,e){e instanceof XMLHttpRequest&&"load"===t[0]&&a.emit("xhr-load-removed",[t[1],t[2]],e)}),a.on("fn-start",function(t,e,n){e instanceof XMLHttpRequest&&("onload"===n&&(this.onload=!0),("load"===(t[0]&&t[0].type)||this.onload)&&(this.xhrCbStart=(new Date).getTime()))}),a.on("fn-end",function(t,e){this.xhrCbStart&&a.emit("xhr-cb-time",[(new Date).getTime()-this.xhrCbStart,this.onload,e],e)})}},{1:"XL7HBI",2:13,3:11,4:7,ee:"QJf3ax",handle:"D5DuLP",loader:"G9z0Bl"}],13:[function(t,e){e.exports=function(t){var e=document.createElement("a"),n=window.location,r={};e.href=t,r.port=e.port;var o=e.href.split("://");return!r.port&&o[1]&&(r.port=o[1].split("/")[0].split("@").pop().split(":")[1]),r.port&&"0"!==r.port||(r.port="https"===o[0]?"443":"80"),r.hostname=e.hostname||n.hostname,r.pathname=e.pathname,r.protocol=o[0],"/"!==r.pathname.charAt(0)&&(r.pathname="/"+r.pathname),r.sameOrigin=!e.hostname||e.hostname===document.domain&&e.port===n.port&&e.protocol===n.protocol,r}},{}],14:[function(t,e){function n(t){return function(){r(t,[(new Date).getTime()].concat(i(arguments)))}}var r=t("handle"),o=t(1),i=t(2);"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=window.NREUM);var a=["setPageViewName","addPageAction","setCustomAttribute","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit","noticeError"];o(a,function(t,e){window.NREUM[e]=n("api-"+e)}),e.exports=window.NREUM},{1:23,2:24,handle:"D5DuLP"}],gos:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("7eSDFh")},{}],"7eSDFh":[function(t,e){function n(t,e,n){if(r.call(t,e))return t[e];var o=n();if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{return Object.defineProperty(t,e,{value:o,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),o}catch(i){}return t[e]=o,o}var r=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=n},{}],D5DuLP:[function(t,e){function n(t,e,n){return r.listeners(t).length?r.emit(t,e,n):(o[t]||(o[t]=[]),void o[t].push(e))}var r=t("ee").create(),o={};e.exports=n,n.ee=r,r.q=o},{ee:"QJf3ax"}],handle:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("D5DuLP")},{}],XL7HBI:[function(t,e){function n(t){var e=typeof t;return!t||"object"!==e&&"function"!==e?-1:t===window?0:i(t,o,function(){return r++})}var r=1,o="nr@id",i=t("gos");e.exports=n},{gos:"7eSDFh"}],id:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("XL7HBI")},{}],loader:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("G9z0Bl")},{}],G9z0Bl:[function(t,e){function n(){var t=l.info=NREUM.info;if(t&&t.licenseKey&&t.applicationID&&f&&f.body){s(h,function(e,n){e in t||(t[e]=n)}),l.proto="https"===p.split(":")[0]||t.sslForHttp?"https://":"http://",a("mark",["onload",i()]);var e=f.createElement("script");e.src=l.proto+t.agent,f.body.appendChild(e)}}function r(){"complete"===f.readyState&&o()}function o(){a("mark",["domContent",i()])}function i(){return(new Date).getTime()}var a=t("handle"),s=t(1),c=(t(2),window),f=c.document,u="addEventListener",d="attachEvent",p=(""+location).split("?")[0],h={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-593.min.js"},l=e.exports={offset:i(),origin:p,features:{}};f[u]?(f[u]("DOMContentLoaded",o,!1),c[u]("load",n,!1)):(f[d]("onreadystatechange",r),c[d]("onload",n)),a("mark",["firstbyte",i()])},{1:23,2:14,handle:"D5DuLP"}],23:[function(t,e){function n(t,e){var n=[],o="",i=0;for(o in t)r.call(t,o)&&(n[i]=e(o,t[o]),i+=1);return n}var r=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=n},{}],24:[function(t,e){function n(t,e,n){e||(e=0),"undefined"==typeof n&&(n=t?t.length:0);for(var r=-1,o=n-e||0,i=Array(0>o?0:o);++r<o;)i[r]=t[e+r];return i}e.exports=n},{}],25:[function(t,e){function n(t){return!(t&&"function"==typeof t&&t.apply&&!t[i])}var r=t("ee"),o=t(1),i="nr@wrapper",a=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=function(t){function e(t,e,r,a){function nrWrapper(){var n,i,s,f;try{i=this,n=o(arguments),s=r&&r(n,i)||{}}catch(d){u([d,"",[n,i,a],s])}c(e+"start",[n,i,a],s);try{return f=t.apply(i,n)}catch(p){throw c(e+"err",[n,i,p],s),p}finally{c(e+"end",[n,i,f],s)}}return n(t)?t:(e||(e=""),nrWrapper[i]=!0,f(t,nrWrapper),nrWrapper)}function s(t,r,o,i){o||(o="");var a,s,c,f="-"===o.charAt(0);for(c=0;c<r.length;c++)s=r[c],a=t[s],n(a)||(t[s]=e(a,f?s+o:o,i,s,t))}function c(e,n,r){try{t.emit(e,n,r)}catch(o){u([o,e,n,r])}}function f(t,e){if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{var n=Object.keys(t);return n.forEach(function(n){Object.defineProperty(e,n,{get:function(){return t[n]},set:function(e){return t[n]=e,e}})}),e}catch(r){u([r])}for(var o in t)a.call(t,o)&&(e[o]=t[o]);return e}function u(e){try{t.emit("internal-error",e)}catch(n){}}return t||(t=r),e.inPlace=s,e.flag=i,e}},{1:24,ee:"QJf3ax"}]},{},["G9z0Bl",4,12,6,5]);</script>\r\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />\r\n    <meta name="fragment" content="!" />\r\n    <title>Authors \xe2\x80\x93 Pluralsight Training</title>\r\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//s.pluralsight.com/sc/css/app-a7dac6e6.css" />\r\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.pluralsight.com/content/dist/css/fonts-a9675ca7.css" />\r\n    <link href=\'//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900\' rel=\'stylesheet\' type=\'text/css\'>\r\n    <!--[if lte IE 9]>\r\n        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//s.pluralsight.com/sc/css/ie-app-1bed8c68.css" />\r\n    <![endif]-->\r\n    <!--[if IE 8]>\r\n         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//s.pluralsight.com/sc/css/ie8-62d3a852.css" />\r\n      <![endif]-->\r\n    <!--[if IE]>\r\n        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//s.pluralsight.com/sc/css/ie-7dd5dc87.css" />\r\n    <![endif]-->\r\n\r\n    <script src="//s.pluralsight.com/sc/js/vendor/custom.modernizr-b4b7741a.js"></script>\r\n\r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    <script src="//cdn.optimizely.com/js/1252788015.js"></script>\r\n\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->\r\n<noscript>\r\n    <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MNK9CB" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>\r\n</noscript>\r\n<script>\r\n    (function (w, d, s, l, i) {\r\n        w[l] = w[l] || [];\r\n        w[l].push({ \'gtm.start\': new Date().getTime(), event: \'gtm.js\' });\r\n        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],\r\n            j = d.createElement(s),\r\n            dl = l != \'dataLayer\' ? \'&l=\' + l : \'\';\r\n        j.async = true;\r\n        j.src = \'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=\' + i + dl;\r\n        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);\r\n    })(window, document, \'script\', \'dataLayer\', \'GTM-MNK9CB\');\r\n</script>\r\n<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->\r\n\r\n    <input type="hidden" id="pageObjectTag" value="AuthorsPage" />\r\n    <div ng-controller="AuthenticationController">\r\n        <div ng-include src="\'/header\'"></div>\r\n\r\n        \r\n\r\n<!-- HERO UNIT -->\r\n<section class="teal-hex-bg hero">\r\n    <div class="row">\r\n        <div class="small-12 columns">\r\n            <h1 class="medium">Our authors</h1>\r\n            <h4 class="normal">Our original courses are authored by an elite group of tech and creative professionals, innovators and leaders. We take pride in only working with the best.</h4>\r\n            <h5 class="authors-invite-to-teach"><strong>Want to join us?</strong></h5>\r\n            <a class="teal button" href="/teach">Learn more</a>\r\n        </div>\r\n    </div>\r\n</section><!-- /HERO UNIT -->\r\n<!-- SECTION TITLE -->\r\n<section class="band" ng-controller="AuthorsController">\r\n\r\n    <div class="row">\r\n        <div class="small-12 columns">\r\n            <div loading show="loading"></div>\r\n            <div class="author-group" ng-cloak ng-repeat="(key, value) in authors">\r\n                <p class="underline">{{key.toUpperCase()}}</p>\r\n                <ul class="inline-list" >\r\n                    <li ng-repeat="author in value"><a class="panel" ng-href="/author/{{author.handle}}">{{author.fullName}}</a></li>\r\n                </ul>\r\n            </div>\r\n        </div>\r\n    </div>\r\n\r\n</section>\r\n\r\n    </div>\r\n    <footer ng-controller="FooterController">\r\n        <div class="row">\r\n            <!-- MAIN FOOTER STUFF -->\r\n            <div class="large-4 columns">\r\n                <img src="//s.pluralsight.com/sc/img/layout/logo-grey-v3.png" class="secondary-logo" />\r\n                <p>\r\n                    Our mission is to publish high quality online training courses for professional developers, IT admins and creative artists. Every day.\r\n                </p>\r\n                <!-- facebook -->\r\n                <a class="facebook social button" href="http://www.facebook.com/pluralsight" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">\r\n                    <span class="icon">\r\n                        <i class="social fi-social-facebook"></i>\r\n                    </span>\r\n                    Facebook\r\n                    <span ng-class="{\'number\': social.likes != undefined}" ng-cloak>{{social.likes | number}}</span>\r\n                </a>\r\n                <!-- twitter -->\r\n                <a class="twitter social button" href="http://twitter.com/pluralsight" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">\r\n                    <span class="icon">\r\n                        <i class="social fi-social-twitter"></i>\r\n                    </span>\r\n                    Twitter\r\n                    <span ng-class="{\'number\': social.followers != undefined}" ng-cloak>{{social.followers | number}}</span>\r\n                </a>\r\n                <!-- google+ -->\r\n                <a class="google social button" href="http://plus.google.com/+pluralsight" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">\r\n                    <span class="icon">\r\n                        <i class="social fi-social-google-plus"></i>\r\n                    </span>\r\n                    Google+\r\n                    <span ng-class="{\'number\': social.plusOnes != undefined}" ng-cloak>{{social.plusOnes | number}}</span>\r\n                </a>\r\n                <!-- newsletter -->\r\n                <p>Subscribe to our newsletter for weekly updates.</p>\r\n                <div class="row collapse signup-form">\r\n                            <form action="https://go.pardot.com/l/36882/2014-08-27/yj3h" method="POST">\r\n                                <div class="small-8 columns">\r\n                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="UserInfo.Email" ng-focus="newsletterEmailFocus()" />\r\n                                </div>\r\n                                <div class="small-4 columns">\r\n                                    <input class="button postfix" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">\r\n                                </div>\r\n                            </form>\r\n\r\n                </div>\r\n            </div>\r\n            <!-- SITE MAP -->\r\n            <div class="large-7 large-offset-1 columns">\r\n                <div class="row">\r\n                    <div class="large-4 columns">\r\n                        <h5>Learn</h5>\r\n                        <ul class="side-nav">\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/tags">Browse Courses</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="http://blog.pluralsight.com/category/learning-paths">Learning Paths</a></li>\r\n                        </ul>\r\n                        <h5>Products</h5>\r\n                        <ul class="side-nav">\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/signup">Individual Plans</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/business">Business Plans</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/a/subscribe/step1?isTrial=True">Free Trial</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/academic">Academic</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/government">Government</a></li>\r\n                        </ul>\r\n                    </div>\r\n                    <div class="large-4 columns">\r\n                        <h5>Community</h5>\r\n                        <ul class="side-nav">\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/kids">Free Kids Courses</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="http://blog.pluralsight.com/">Official Blog</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/studygroups">Study Groups</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/sponsorships">UG &amp; Event Sponsorships</a></li>\r\n                        </ul>\r\n                        <h5>Support</h5>\r\n                        <ul class="side-nav">\r\n                            <li><a href="http://support.pluralsight.com" rel="nofollow">Ask Support a Question</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="http://support.pluralsight.com/forums/127919-new-course-suggestions" rel="nofollow">Suggest a Course</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/training/support/uservoiceoutbound" rel="nofollow">Support &amp; Feedback</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/training/support/knowledgebaseoutbound" rel="nofollow">Knowledge Base / FAQ</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="http://blog.pluralsight.com/terms-of-use" rel="nofollow">Terms of Use</a></li>\r\n                        </ul>\r\n                    </div>\r\n                    <div class="large-4 columns">\r\n                        <h5>Features</h5>\r\n                        <ul class="side-nav">\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/training/products/mobileplayers">Mobile Apps</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/training/products/offlineviewing">Offline Viewing</a></li>\r\n                        </ul>\r\n                        <h5>About</h5>\r\n                        <ul class="side-nav">\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/contact">Contact Us</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="http://blog.pluralsight.com/press">Press Center</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/about">About Us</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/authors">Authors</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="//www.pluralsight.com/teach">Teach</a></li>\r\n                            <li><a href="http://pluralsight.mytribehr.com/careers/index" target="_blank">Jobs at Pluralsight</a></li>\r\n                        </ul>\r\n                    </div>\r\n                </div>\r\n            </div>\r\n        </div>\r\n    </footer>\r\n\r\n    <script src="//s.pluralsight.com/sc/js/bundled/vendor-46f7b492.js"></script>\r\n    <script src="//s.pluralsight.com/sc/js/bundled/app-d238c035.js"></script>\r\n\r\n\r\n    <script type="text/javascript">\r\n        pluralsightModule.factory(\'baseUrls\', function () {\r\n            return {\r\n                dataUrl: \'/data\',\r\n                mvcUrl: \'//www.pluralsight.com/a\',\r\n                mainWebUrl: \'//www.pluralsight.com/training\',\r\n                staticCdnUrl: \'http://s.pluralsight.com\',\r\n                staticUrl: \'//www.pluralsight.com\',\r\n                contentUrl: \'//s.pluralsight.com/sc\'\r\n            };\r\n        })\r\n        .factory(\'validationService\', function () {\r\n            return {\r\n                emailAddressPattern: \'/^[a-zA-Z0-9&#39;._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-][a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$/\'\r\n            };\r\n        })\r\n        .factory(\'settingsProvider\', function ($resource) {\r\n            return {\r\n                    featureToggleMarketoFormHandlers: String(false) == \'true\',\r\n                    featureToggleLinkedIn: String(false) == \'true\'\r\n                };\r\n        });\r\n        \r\n\r\n    </script>\r\n\r\n    <script type="text/javascript">\r\n        var hero = $(".hero") || $("header");\r\n        hero.after(\'<div class="global-message-bar" ng-cloak ng-controller="MessageBarController" ng-show="hasMessage()"><div class="row"><div class="small-12 columns"><a href="#" ng-click="clearMessage()" class="close-message-bar"><i class="fi-x"></i></a><span class="message-text">{{getMessage()}}</span></div></div></div>\');\r\n    </script>\r\n\r\n    \r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

Or use requests:

```
 import requests

 r = requests.get("http://www.pluralsight.com/authors")

 print(r.content)
```